# What happens if some threads ends first than others?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I'm working to parallelize the search pattern with automatons in CUDA.

So, each thread will take a different "word" to see if it is accepted by the automaton.

I want to know if there is any problem when thinking about warp divergence when some threads ends first than others.

Let's say that thread 1 take word 1 and thread 2 take word 2 (and so on until 32)...

If the threads with an even number (just an assumption) finish the work first, and the odd threads keep running, does it have a big impact in warp divergence or in any other efficiency problem? Or it does no impact in efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, warp divergence impacts efficiency.

However, warp divergence is not some kind of problem that you must try to avoid at all costs.  Many many CUDA codes experience some level of warp divergence.

The fact that a particular algorithm leads to warp divergence is not necessarily a reason not to try it.

If you are optimizing an algorithm and you discover warp divergence to be a prevalent issue (say, using the visual profiler) then you might try and think of ways to reduce it.  But the final measure of your code is it's overall performance, not it's level of warp divergence.  And reducing warp divergence is only valuable if it leads to improved performance.

If you have another alternative algorithm in mind that doesn't lead to divergence, and is doing useful work with all the threads and machine cycles, it may well be faster. But unless you already have that algorithm in mind, the point is moot.  Presumably you must implement something, right?

No one can tell from your description how much warp divergence would affect your code.  It depends on things like *how far ahead the even threads finish their work* (and are therefore idle).  And even then, this only matters if you know of a better way to craft it without divergence.

The divergence is simply an indicator of a possible area for improvement in your code.

If you know of a pattern in the data that will predict thread execution time, then you might try and re-organize your data to group elements with similar processing times together.  This will tend to minimize the efficiency impact of divergence.  Some GPU sorting codes do this, I think.  In your case, if you could re-arrange your data to group the even elements together (if they lead to "shorter" threads), you could exploit a similar technique for reducing the efficiency impact of divergence.  Of course it's possible that the time-cost of reorganizing the data might outweigh the time-benefit of improved efficiency in the presence of warp divergence.

Comment: A complete question, answering all that i've asked and giving one advice. Thanks!